# Rail 4 populating select field with val of other select field

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, select, ruby-on-rails-4

After I read a lot of samples.. I still have a mistake in my code. I cant figure out whats wrong.
Can somebody give me a hint?

view: A form with two select fields

```
<%= select_tag "ops_group_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@groups, "id", "name"), :prompt => "Select a group"%>
<%= render :partial => 'oncalls' %>
```

route:

```
 get "/projects/update_oncalls/:id" => 'projects#update_oncalls'
```

controller:

```
def update_oncalls
    @oncalls = Oncall.where(:group_id => params[:id])
    render :partial => "oncalls", oncalls: @oncalls
  end
```

partial oncalls:

```
<%= form.input :oncall_id, :as => :select, :collection => @oncalls, :label => false %>
```

coffee:

```
$(document).on "change", "select#ops_group_id", ->
 opsgroup = $("select#ops_group_id :selected").val()
 opsgroup = "0"  if opsgroup is ""
 jQuery.get "/projects/update_oncalls/" + opsgroup, (data) ->
 $("#project_oncall_id").html (data)
 return
```

in log:   Oncall Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "oncalls".* FROM "oncalls" WHERE "oncalls"."group_id" = 1
  Rendered projects/_oncalls.html.erb (3.9ms)

But the oncalls select ist not filled..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your render generates a new select, and your jQuery here `$("#project_oncall_id").html (data)` is trying to place that select inside your existing one.

Try `$("#project_oncall_id").replaceWith(data)` instead.

EDIT: Also double-check that the id of the second select is indeed `project_oncall_id` and not `oncall_id`.

Comment: Thanks..this looks better now..it is really 'project_oncall_id'